# Вилку, не ложку(,) с брокколи

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

`Я обычно использую вилку, не ложку(,) с брокколи.`

Как я понимаю, здесь она не нужна.

`Я обычно использую вилку, а не ложку с брокколи.`

Comment: скорее всего нужна в обоих случаях, иначе "с брокколи" тоже идет в противопоставление с вилкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ситуация: на столе имеются только ложки; кто-то очень настойчиво и нервно просит принести (подать) ему вилку. Тогда я бы такие поставила знаки:

*Я обычно использую вилку — не ложку! — с брокколи.

Я обычно использую вилку, а не ложку — с брокколи.*

Ложку в тексте надо обязательно отделить от брокколи, чтобы была пауза. Иначе возникает ощущение, что говорящий использует *ложку с брокколи* (ложку, наполненную капустой).
С тире такая пауза длиннее, чётче.
Чаще всего в таких конструкциях все-таки используется предлог **для**: вилка для рыбы, ложка для салата, нож для масла, ложечка для кофе.

Нейтральный вариант:
*Для брокколи я обычно использую вилку, а не ложку.*

Comment: А если такое предложение? *Мы чаще используем **a**, не **an**, в английском языке.*

Comment: У вас ведь такой вопрос есть... «Я подумаю об этом завтра»...